# Providing custom __str__ representation for an attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm sold on the idea of providing a `__str__` for classes in Python, but, especially now that data classes are a thing, I've found a need for defining `__str__` for attributes of a class.  Here is an extremely contrived example:

```py
class Example():
    what = ['t', 'e', 's', 't']

    def __init__(self, is_test=True):
        self.is_test = is_test

    def __str__(self):
        if self.is_test:
            return f'This is just a {"".join(self.what)}'
        return f'This is not a {"".join(self.what)}'

    def print_what(self):
        return "".join(self.what)

a = Example()

> print(a)
This is just a test

> print(a.print_what())
test   

> print(a.what)
['t', 'e', 's', 't']
```

What I want to do is follow the same `__str__` pattern from the class for the `what` attribute so that `print(a.what)` would show `test` instead of `['t', 'e', 's', 't']`.  Is it possible to provide a `__str__` representation for an attribute?  Perhaps with something like a decorator?

Comment: You can't do that without constraining the actual type of `what`. Your idea to do `print_what` is much better. Either that, or use a custom descriptor that returns a specialized proxy. Hang on, I have a terrible solution to write up.

Comment: I assume that in your actual case `Example.what` is an instance of a custom class? In that case all you have to do is implement `__str__` there

Comment: @DeepSpace: In my actual code the "Example.what" stand in is actually just a list, but I had thought about creating a class for it and implementing __str__ there (as silly as that would be).  In reality, the print function is far more complicated than the above example.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Can't wait for that crazy solution, but what do you mean by "constraining the actual type of `what`"?

Comment: @Zack. Sorry, actual work intervened. All will be explained as soon as the meetings end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start by simplifying your test class:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.what = list('test')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'This is a {self.what!s}'
```

Your goal is to make an instance print `This is a test`, not `This is a ['t', 'e', 's', 't']`, and for `print(Example().what)` to behave similarly by extension.

This is not as trivial as it may sound, because `what` can be any type at all. The user can set it to whatever they want in the current class, so if you don't constrain the type, you have no control over what `str(Example().what)` returns.

Another level of complication comes from the fact that python magic methods are optimized to only look at the class implementation. For example:

```
class Test:
    x = 1
    def __str__(self):
        return str(x)

t = Test()
t.__str__ = lambda: return '2'
```

In this case, `print(str(t))` will print `1`, not `2`. This is because instance attributes are ignored in magic method lookup. Internally, `str(t)` does (approximately) `type(t).__str__(t)`, not `t.__str__()`.

Given all this background, I would propose a couple of possible solutions:

1. Use a `property` to control the type of the internal object. You can wrap in a type that has the necessary `__str__` attribute,  but also gives access to the original object:

   ```
   class Wrapper:
       def __init__(self, target):
           self.obj = target
       def __str__(self):
           return ''.join(self.obj)

   class Example:
       def __init__(self):
            self.what = list('test')

       def __str__(self):
            return f'This is a {self.what!s}'

       @property
       def what(self):
           return self.__dict__['what']

       @what.setter
       def what(self, value):
           self.__dict__['what'] = Wrapper(value)
   ```
2. Extend option #1 to use a proper proxy object that only overrides `__str__`. This will allow you to interact directly with `Example().what` instead of `Example().what.obj`.

   ```
   class Proxy:
       def __init__(self, target):
           self.obj = target

       def __str__(self):
           return ''.join(self.obj)

   class Example:
       ...
       @what.setter
       def what(self, value):
           self.__dict__['what'] = Proxy(value)
   ```

   The only issue is that if you re-implement `__str__` on the proxy but not other dunder methods (such as `__len__` or `__getitem__`), your proxy basically won't work. Remember that the dunder attributes can't be proxied directly, since they aren't looked up with `__getattribute__` like normal attributes when their magic function is invoked.

   You can either manually implement all known dunder attributes, or use a metaclass to generate them for you. What you can't do, unfortunately, is implement `__getattribute__` on the metaclass to trap lookups into your class, because the lookups don't happen that way for dunders.

   Here is a small example of a proxy with some generated methods. You can select the methods you want to generate:

   ```
   class ProxyMeta(type):
       dunders = ('add', 'radd', 'iadd', 'len', 'iter', 'getitem', 'setitem')
       target_attr = 'obj'

       def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
           def get_dunder(name):
               def dunder(self, *args, **kwargs):
                   return getattr(getattr(self, cls.target_attr), name)(*args, **kwargs)
               dunder.__name__ = name
               return dunder

           for name in cls.dunders:
               name = f'__{name}__'
               setattr(cls, name, get_dunder(name))

   class Proxy(metaclass=ProxyMeta):
       def __init__(self, target):
           self.obj = target

       def __str__(self):
           return ''.join(self.obj)
   ```

   The only thing this updated proxy won't do (if set up correctly), is report that it is an instance of the target type when you call `isinstance` on it.

Comment: @alkasm. I fixed the preemptive click on submit

Comment: Wow, that's all very helpful.  I've gone with a proxy object type approach, but your post definitely helped me understand a bit of what's going on in the back-end.  I wish I had a few more StackOverflow points so I could upvote your answer (unfortunately, my old account got wiped out due to a SSO issue).

Comment: @Zack. You could always select the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a property in this case.
e.g:

```
class Example:
    _data = ['t','e','s','t']

    @property
    def data(self):
        return "".join(self._data)



a = Example()

> print(a.data)
test
```

Comment: Ok, that might work, though it makes me realize that I've been stupid in my understanding of the @property decorator.  I don't know why I didn't think of just using the fget to print a private variable.  I'm going to mark this one as the winner!

Comment: I guess the one thing that this approach still lacks a little on is that I can't have a different repr and str for the data property, but maybe I can make that work.